Create date periods based on two tables
CREATE TABLE "TEST1" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATE_FROM" DATE, 
    "DATE_TO" DATE
);

CREATE TABLE "TEST2" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "PERCENT" NUMBER(5,4), 
    "DATE_FROM" DATE
);
   
INSERT INTO test1 (ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO)
VALUES (546, to_date('01-12-2005', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('01-12-2006', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

INSERT INTO test1 (ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO)
VALUES (546, to_date('01-12-2006', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('01-07-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

INSERT INTO test1 (ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO)
VALUES (546, to_date('01-07-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('31-12-4712', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

INSERT INTO test2 (ID, PERCENT, DATE_FROM)
VALUES (546, 0.0100, to_date('01-12-2005', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

INSERT INTO test2 (ID, PERCENT, DATE_FROM)
VALUES (546, 0.0450, to_date('01-12-2009', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

What I'm trying to achieve is put date periods from table2 into table1, so it look like this

But I have absolutely no idea how to achieve it. I need four records, Cartesian makes 6, I'm trying with where conditions (and t2.date_From not between t1.date_From and t2.date_From or t1.date_from=t2.date_From) but then t2.date_From is missing.
This is a sample data, SQL which is generating this data is large, so I would like to avoid calling these tables multiple times.
Thanks!
EDIT: I found one way to do this, maybe someone has a better idea, but looks like it works:
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t1.date_from,
         t1.date_to,
         t2.percent,
         t2.date_from AS date_from2,
         t2.max_date,
         NVL(GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_From), t1.date_from) AS new_vf,
         NVL(GREATEST(NVL(LEAD(GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_From)) OVER (ORDER BY t1.date_from ASC), t1.date_to), t2.date_From), t1.date_to) AS new_vt
     FROM   
         test1 t1
     LEFT JOIN   
         (SELECT  
              t3.*,
              MAX(date_from) OVER() AS max_Date
          FROM    
              test2 t3) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                           AND t2.max_date BETWEEN t1.date_From AND t1.date_to
    ) t
ORDER BY 
    t.date_From ASC, t.date_to ASC


Can you explain the logic behind the expected result?

Contract starts with some param value, then this param changing during contract life. We are migrating data so history model needs to look like this

That's a bad explanation. To me it looks like you have that table of date ranges you want to show. You also want to add a row starting from the last to_date into some faraway future (4712-12-31). Then for each of these rows you want to show the most recent percentage in regards to the range's start_date? or its end_date? Or would a percentage row with a date somewhere between a range's start and end split that range?

You have two data sets. Look at them, look at screenshot from excel - it is easy.

Nope it isn't. Have I guessed right? Is the 4712-12-31 row created thus? Or is there some logic to get to that date? And my questions have not been answered. We cannot read your mind, and unfortunately for you, the DBMS can't either. On a side note: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

No, You did not guessed right.  You shouldn't be interested in how data is generated in the first table, because question is how to insert data from 2nd. Look at SQL which I add recently.

"Then for each of these rows you want to show the most recent percentage in regards to the range's start_date" - yes, as screen shows.

You can use the LEAD analytic function to generate the next date for TEST2 and then join when the date ranges overlap:
SELECT t1.id,
       GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_from) AS date_from,
       LEAST(t1.date_to, t2.date_to) AS date_to,
       t2.percent
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                percent,
                date_from,
                LEAD(date_from, 1, DATE '4712-12-31')
                  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_from) AS date_to
         FROM   test2
       ) t2
       INNER JOIN test1 t1
       ON     t1.id        = t2.id
          AND t1.date_from < t2.date_to
          AND t2.date_from < t1.date_to

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ID
DATE_FROM
DATE_TO
PERCENT




546
2005-12-01 00:00:00
2006-12-01 00:00:00
.01


546
2006-12-01 00:00:00
2009-12-01 00:00:00
.01


546
2009-12-01 00:00:00
2011-07-01 00:00:00
.045


546
2011-07-01 00:00:00
4712-12-31 00:00:00
.045



fiddle

Exactly the same as I thought, but Your idea with LEAD in inner SQL is better. Thanks :)

could You explain  LEAD(date_from, 1, DATE '4712-12-31')? I always put only 1 column

@q4za4 The LEAD Documentation explains that the arguments are LEAD(value_expr, offset, default) ... the default offset is 1 and the default default is NULL, which I've replaced with the magic date that you appear to be using for an unknown future date.
